# Components from Vue.js are not loaded in Laravel blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

Installed vue js with node modules for laravel 5.4 project but the components are not displayed after I run npm run watch

Installed npm, installed vue.js added vue.js file example in app.js, npm run watch - no result

blade template file

```
  <div id="app">
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <h2>asda</h2>
      <example-component></example-component>
  </div>
```

App.js

```
 import Vue from 'vue';

 Vue.component('example-component', 
 require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));



    //Set toaster duration
    Vue.config.productionTip = false

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {

        }
  })
```

The component should be loaded after page refresh but is not. No any error messages in console.

Comment: clean the browser cache,and do you have imported the app.js file within the blade file?

Comment: Cleared browser cache and view cache, still not loading. Should I import manually app.js file in blade if I have installed it via npm?

Comment: yeap you should do that by your self

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using Webpack, you should append the `require(...)` with `.default` so it becomes `require(...).default`. Example in [Laravel Git](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/ebc6f6e2c794b07c6d432483fd654aebf2ffe222/resources/js/app.js#L22)
2. Make sure that you `export default` in your components. Example in [Laravel Git](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/ebc6f6e2c794b07c6d432483fd654aebf2ffe222/resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue#L18)

Comment: Added .default in app.js but is not helping. In example component I have export default function. Usually npm and vue install was enough to run templates from blade.